# How do I map into a single entity, these three tables, where the thrird acts as an association

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a question about multiple table mapping to a single entity with different key names.

Suppose the following tables:

```
table cs_One
(
    oneID,    -- pk
    colOne1,
    colOne2
)

table two
(
    domainID, -- fk to domain
    colTwo1,
    colTwo2,
)

table domain
(
    domainID, -- pk
    CSoneID,  -- fk to cs_one
    col1,
    col2,
)

public class entAll 
{
    int oneID;
    int domainID;
    int CSoneID;
    colOne1;
    colOne2;
    colTwo1;
    colTwo2;
}
```

my mapping

```
public class entAllMap : EntinyTypeConfiguration<entAll>
{
    public entAllMap()
    {
        HasKey(e => new { e.oneID, e.domainID })
        .Map(e =>
            {
                e.Properties(c => new
                {
                    c.oneID,
                    c.ColOne1,
                    c.ColOne2,
                });
                e.ToTable("cs_one");
            })
        .Map(e => 
            {
                e.Properties(c => new
                {
                    c.domainID,
                    c.ColTwo1,
                    c.ColTwo2,
                });
                e.ToTable("two");
            })
        .Map(e =>
            {
                e.Properties(c => new 
                {
                    c.domainID,
                    c.CSoneID,
                });
                e.ToTable("domain");
            });
    }
}
```

Here is the query I expect and need (with regard to the joining)

```
select t1.[oneID], t1.[col1], t1.[col2], t2.[domainID], t2.[col1], t2.[col2]
from [cs_one] t1
join [domain] d1 on t1.[oneID] = t1.[CSoneID]
join [two] t2 on d1.[domainID] = t2.[domainID]
```

the query i am getting is something like the following:

```
select t1.[oneID], t1.[col1], t1.[col2], t2.[domainID], t2.[col1], t2.[col2]
from [domain] d1
join [two] t2 on d1.[domainID] = t1.[domainID]
join [cs_one] t1 on t2.[domainID] = t1.[domainID]
```

How do I map into a single entity, these three tables, where the thrird acts as an association table of sorts.
I cannot change the key names.  I cannot alter the tables.

My objective is to create a single entity using these three pseudo tables.  The catch is that the table (domain) that ties the other two (cs_one and two) has a foreign key column name that is different than the target column.  The following join is where I am finding difficulty:

```
join [domain] d1 on t1.[oneID] = t1.[CSoneID]
```

It would work if I could specify the fk => pk column names and relationship in the mapping - and this is actually what I am looking for.  Is there such a method/property/helper - I cannot seem to find one.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research I have found - via MS docs - that this cannot be done.
I have submitted a request for an enhancement that will allow a developer to explicitly define the relationships between entities, database tables and each other.

Alas, I have resorted to Linq To SQL - A good direction too.

Thanks to everyone,
Jim